black and white movie about orphans and opening a school
It's one of those classic black and white movies back in 40s and 50s i believe. 
There is this man who adopts some kids I think. On Christmas I think, he brings home some used presents for the kids and they are not happy. He also had a friend/colleague that owned some kind of a store. He asks his friend to help him build a school for orphans I believe. Don't know if they were orphans or it was a boarding school for teens. I do remember a teen boxing match taking place in that school. It could have been all boys school. Can't remember if there were any girls.
Anyone know what movie this might be? 

Sounds like Boys Town from 1938 with Spencer Tracy and Mickey Rooney about a priest opening up a sanctuary for abandoned boys. From an online recap:

the story of the real life crusading Catholic priest Father Flanagan, who embarks on a scheme to rescue abandoned, abused and hopeless boys from the streets... with the help of the cranky but secretly sympathetic pawn shop owner Dave Morris

There's also a boxing match in which Rooney's character is beaten up. Here's the trailer.
